# Steel filings just like iron filings?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am having problems with an experiment involving field lines.

I filed a piece of steel to get "iron filings." Ought these steel filings be vastly different from the iron filings typically used in this sort of experiment?

Answer (score 2):

There are two differences I can see.  The iron filings I have used for magnetic field visualization are long and thin.  The steel filings I generate in my workshop are more like disks.  They won't help to visualize the field well.  Also you might have a non-magnetic steel.  Some steels, particularly some stainless, have a nonmagnetic crystal structure.

Comment: This steel is not stainless; it was rusted before I began filing at it (I discarded the rust filings)
Also the filings I get are definitely rod shaped. When I place them in a cup and put a magnet under the cup, they form a spiny clump.

Comment: Note that "stainless" steel usually becomes magnetic when worked. For example, most stainless threaded screws and bolts are noticeably attracted to magnets — not as much as soft iron, but too much for low-magnetic field applications.

Comment: @rob:  I believe the 400 series is magnetic even without working.  It depends on the crystal structure.